# Material Angular progress bar does not update value ( with observables )

Tags: angular, angular-material, progress-bar, server-sent-events

I'm writing an angular app and a spring boot program to see the Server Event Stream.
I'm using the material progress bar in this way:

```
<mat-progress-bar  mode="determinate" [value]="progressValue"></mat-progress-bar>
```

The progressValue is calculated in the component.ts, in this way:

```
getEventStream(){
this.progressValue = 0;

this.mySub = this.docServ.getEvents().pipe().subscribe(
  (res:MyMessage) => {
    console.log("COMP");
    console.log(res)
    console.log(" ");
    this.progressValue =  Math.round(( res.currentIndex / res.finalIndex ) * 100);
    console.log(this.progressValue)
  };}
```

As you can see from the code, I use the value res.currentIndex / res.finalIndex to set the progress of the material progress bar.
From the log I could see that the data from the server are arriving correctly:
[image]

The problem is that the material progress bar is not updating ( despite the variable this.progressValue is correctly updated ) UNTIL I CLICK somewhere on the browser page!!!!

Any suggestion?

UPDATE:
I solved the problem using this (but I still don't understand which is the problem) [image]

Comment: Calling detectChanges() like you did here works. It's what I went with first. I believe the real issue is that we're somehow running outside of the NgZone. I don't know enough about the zone to know how or why. But injecting NgZone in the component constructor, and wrapping the change in a callback like this does the trick. this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.progressAmount = v;
        });

Comment: Using async pipe didn't work in my situation either. Thought I'd mention that as well.

Comment: That really sucks. In my case, I even had to resort to `setTimeout(() => this.cdr.detectChanges(), 0)` or it wouldn't work - most likely because I'm calling it from inside `.pipe(tap())`, not inside `.subscribe()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the change detection isn't triggered when `this.progressValue` is set. You could instead try to use the `async` pipe.

***.ts**

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export someComponent implements OnInit {
  const progress$: Observable<number>;

  constructor() { ... }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.progress$ = this.docServ.getEvents().pipe(
      map((res: MyMessage) => Math.round((res.currentIndex / res.finalIndex) * 100.))
    );
  }
}
```

***.html**

```html
<mat-progress-bar  mode="determinate" [value]="(progress$ | async) || 0"></mat-progress-bar>
```

Comment: already tried, same result: no changes until i click on the screen

Comment: @S-Wing: Strange indeed, I might need more information to look into the issue further.

Comment: which information do you need?

Comment: I'm using async pipe. And the changes don't appear when I click either the screen either. But if I call detectChanges() 2 seconds later, the changes appear.

Answer (score 0):

When are you calling getEventStream(). I believe on clicking you getEventStream is being called, and soon after it gets called, you are unsubscribing. So, you can unsubscribe to observable in ngOnDestroy().